# Multiple XMLHttpRequest.send() not working

Tags: javascript

Im using Multiple

```
//process1
xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
var url = context+"/user_permission.do?&method=allotedContainer&row="+data;
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = allotedContainerChanged;
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.send(null);

//process2
xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
var url = context+"/user_permission.do?&method=notwallotedContainer&row="+data;
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = notallotedContainerChanged;
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

when i run both process the second only gets printed. but first one is not responding...

Comment: Does GetXmlHttpObject return the same object?

Comment: if you're running them at the same time, perhaps use a different variable name rather than `xmlHttp` for both?

Comment: different variable name works handsomely... thanks for rapid help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the variable name 'xmlHttp' for the second process and ensure the URL is correct or not . I assume 'method=notwallotedContainer' may have a spellling mistake.